# Finding the line number of a specific string in a text file using Delphi

Tags: string, function, delphi-2009

I want to implement a Delphi function which returns the line number and occurrence of a specific string inside a text file. say in the given text file one of the line is: `#1.1 Torsional Stiffness [Tz]` along with other text data.

If I want to find out where `Torsional Stiffness` is seated in the text file, what Delphi code should be implemented??

The below program works and helps me find a particular string inside the text file.

The *string* is visually found on line number 4 `(sl[i] = sl[4])` of the assigned text file (*using RAD debug layout*). But I want my program to automatically output the line where my string is located and also count the number of occurrences of the same in the `.txt` file.

```pascal
program findingText;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Dialogs,
  Classes;

procedure FindText;
var
  sl: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  searchText: string;
  //fileName: TextFile;

begin
 searchText  := 'Torsional Stiffness matrices';
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.LoadFromFile('c:\Users\fro.txt');
    for i := 0 to sl.Count-1 do
      if Pos(searchText, sl[i])>0 then
        begin
          ShowMessage('Yes');
          //ShowMessage(sl[i]);
          Break;
        end;
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
 FindText;
 //readln;
end.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we generally can't write programs from scratch for people, since there obviously would be too many requests for that from the general public. Do you have some code you've tried that's giving you trouble?

Comment: The below program works and helps me find a particular string inside the text file. The 'string' is visually found on line number 4 (sl[i] = sl[4]) of the assigned text file(using RAD debug layout). But I want my program to automatically output the line where my string is located and also count the number of occurrences of the same in the .txt file

Answer (score 0):

As with any problem, there will many possible approaches. I don't have a particular solution but I would start by loading the text into a string list. TStringList has a **LoadFromFile** method and the **ItemIndex** property will then provide the line number. You would still need to work out the best method to search for a given string. A **for/next** loop iterating through the items in the string list would be easiest. If the file is relatively small then this approach is very simple and effective. You'd need to experiment as to how large the file could go before speed became an issue.